Limit of a product of infinite terms given by splitting into infinite limits
I came across the following limit of product of infinite terms. But the solutions given in the web was by taking separate limit of each term of the infinite terms and taking the product. I have learnt that we can't split limit of product into product of limit when there are infinite terms. So what should be the correct approach?
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} n^{-n^2}[(n+1)(n+1/2)...(n+1/2^{n-1})]^n$$
Link to solution
I am a high school student so please explain it in simple terms.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2744809/42969 – that is the same question, only with $2$ replaced by $3$.

@MartinR Thank you. But in the linked question, they write those terms with n in the denominator as zero right? That is they are directly applying limit n tends to inf for each term in the second last step?

You're right that the posted solution is invalid (even though the numerical answer might end up being correct). The specific flaw is in the third equals sign: there's no justification why a limit of an increasing (but finite at every step) number of terms should equal an infinite product of constants. It seems like the same "proof" would show that $$1 = \lim_{n\to\infty} 1 = \lim_{n\to\infty} (\underbrace{\tfrac1n+\tfrac1n+\cdots+\tfrac1n}_{n\text{ times}}) = 0 + 0 + \cdots = 0.$$

@GregMartin So how do we continue from the step? I couldn't think of any other way to continue and the solutions given on other websites too make the same mistake.

I would take the approach in the answer that Martin R linked to.

@GregMartin In the linked answer by Martin R also, in the last step they are ignoring $$O(1/n3^r)$$ right? But what's the reason for that unless we apply limit n tends to infinity to each term?

Although they didn't fill in all the steps, they're not ignoring that term. They're using the fact that $\sum_{r=0}^{n-1} 3^{-r} = \frac32+o(1)$ (indeed it's $\frac32 + O(3^{-n})$) and the fact that $\sum_{r=0}^{n-1} n^{-1}3^{-r} = o(1)$ (indeed it's $O(n^{-1}$).
